# Flutter build windows

Tags: flutter, build, window, exe

im trying to build an app for windows with flutter

it's my first time to do so, what i want to try is to build my app that i build for android into a windows app just to test it out.

when i ran "flutter build windows" it ran for couple of second with "build windows application message".

[image: terminal log]

but then it stopped, it opened a new line of terminal with no confirmation either its success or failed. and i cant find the release folder in my windows/runner/ folder. so i assumed that it failed

Can u explain why it happened? and other than package that only can be ran in android app is there anything else that i have to worried or change before build my android app into windows app,

Thankyou

i already tried to "flutter clean" or "flutter doctor" to check if everythings fine.

and i already try to google it also but find no luck, thankyou for your time <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relase folder is in cash**\build\windows\runner,not cash**\windows\runner.